# Visual Studio 2010SP1 locks up when typing class=" in MVC3 project using razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, razor

Sometimes, not always, Visual Studio locks up when typing `class="` on any element. This doesn't happen all the time and I can't seem to identify a pattern other than VS has usually been running for a while.

Also, I have ELMAH installed and set to email me on exceptions. Relatively often, although not always I get an email when typing `class="` like below.  Why would it be trying to start the project when typing class?

```
System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path
  '/Views/TechSupport/@Url.Content(' was not found
  or does not implement IController.
```

To resolve the issue I restart Visual Studio. Sometimes the problem persists and I need to restart it again.  Usually it works properly at that point, without the above ELMAH email.  If not then I reboot.

This is my only MVC project, so I don't know if it's specific to this project or not. It did seem to happen very early on in the development process though. This only happens when I type class=", nothing else triggers a crash/lockup.

**EDIT - ADDITIONAL INFO:**
For some reason, when I just typed class="  an error dialog box popped with the message 
`Cannot load "c:\Progra~1\MICROS~2.0\Common7\Packages\vwd\mso.dll"`
When I click OK I get a second dialog box that says 
`Visual Studio has encountered an exception. This may be caused by an extension.`
It then goes on to suggest I use the /log parameter when start VS, which I will be trying now.

Comment: +1: I have this problem but I don't have ELMAH installed so I never had any idea what was causing it.  Interesting that it's doing what it is.

Comment: it happens with a pure install too. I put it down to a VS 2010 bug

Comment: See my update to my answer, and provide more information. Like is it when your using razor views (I assume it is, could be an intelli-sence issue)? Is it in MVC3 or MVC4? MVC4 seems to have this issue more often. It only happens when you type `class=`, nothing else? Does it only do it for this one project or has it happened on others?

Comment: @Ga Actually I have most those questions covered in the subject. My guess was intelli-sense, but I honestly have no idea what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found that by going to the `Extension Manager -> Online Gallery` and search install the `Web Standards Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 sp1` Fixes it.

You may have to uninstall it and re-install it if it's already installed.

**Update**

Here is some other info that may help:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/c249aa35-ed66-431a-9cc3-03b0b84f5f21/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpide/thread/ac74d91c-b76d-49a3-b599-a8f19df9303a

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/727091/visual-studio-crashes-when-editing-an-mvc-4-beta-cshtml

- Open Options->Text Editor->CSS->Miscellaneous and disable "Statement Completion"
- Also in the General section there are other "Statement Completion" options.
- Try closing the project, deleting the contents of the "bin" folder inside the Project folder (you might backup your project before), then re-open the project.
- As a last resort you can try creating a new project and re-importing the project & code files, or even repairing/re-installing VS.
- Try "Enable Insert attibute value quotes when typing" on Tool -> Options -> TextEditor -> HTML -> Formatting

Comment: So far so good on this answer, installed over the weekend. I received what appeared to be a momentary lock up when I fist typed class=" today, but it released and everything is fine. I am still receiving the ELMAH emails. Going to keep testing for a while before accepting the answer.

Comment: @Crob hope it works, another thing that solved some strange Visual Studio problems (wasn't my intent, but it seems to have solved them anyway,) was updating `NuGet`. It had been saying I needed to update it for a while, however whenever I tried it would always fail. I found a HotFix that solved this. Let me know if you need more info. I've never used or looked into `ELMAH`, it sends you an email even if the error is an issue with VS, or is the `Exception` thrown during debug?

Comment: I use ELMAH to report on all exceptions, so for some reason VS is trying to run the application when typing class=".

Comment: The day after I accepted this answer I was typing class=" and I then VS crashed. Not a lock up, but that wasn't always consistent either.

Comment: @Crob Strange, make sure you post your answer when you figure it out. Does this happen on more than one project?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will check them out.  Yeah, this is my only MVC project to date though.